# android, asyntaskloader, simpleadapter

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, loader, listadapter

I am very confused with AsynctaskLoader. I use Asynctaskloader to load JSON data from server using PHP, but still received an error.

This is my code:

```
public class ProdukListFragment2 extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

private static final String proUrl = "http://bsamon.com/salesmonitoring/list_produk2.php";

private EditText searchprod;

private static final int LOADER_LOAD_DATA = 0;

// Creating JSON Parser object
static JSONHelper jParser = new JSONHelper();

//static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// products JSONArray
static JSONArray products = null;

ListAdapter adapter;

private ListView listView;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUK = "tb_barang";
private static final String TAG_KODE_PRODUK = "kode_barang";
private static final String TAG_TIPE_PRODUK = "tipe_barang";

String kodepro;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getListView();
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_prod_layout, container, false);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e16505"));
return view;
}
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_LOAD_DATA, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProdukLoader loader = new ProdukLoader(getActivity());

    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> loader, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> produk) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] from = new String[]
            {
                TAG_TIPE_PRODUK,
                TAG_KODE_PRODUK
            };

    int[] to = new int[]
            {
                R.id.listnamaprod,
                R.id.listkodeprod
            };

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), produk, R.layout.list_prod, from, to);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> loader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listView.setAdapter(null);
}

// ---------- Loader --------------
public static class ProdukLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> produk;

    public ProdukLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> loadInBackground() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(proUrl, "GET", params);

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1)
            {
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUK);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jObj = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String kodePro = jObj.getString(TAG_KODE_PRODUK);
                    String tipePro = jObj.getString(TAG_TIPE_PRODUK);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_KODE_PRODUK, kodePro);
                    map.put(TAG_TIPE_PRODUK, tipePro);

                    produk.add(map);
                }
            } else
            {
                //trhtrh
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return produk;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReset();
        produk = null;
        onStopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCanceled(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStartLoading();
        if (produk !=null)
        {
            deliverResult(produk);
        } else
        {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }
}
}
```

Result of Logcat:

```
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:240)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.bimasakti.samon.ProdukListFragment2.onLoadFinished(ProdukListFragment2.java:149)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.bimasakti.samon.ProdukListFragment2.onLoadFinished(ProdukListFragment2.java:1)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.bimasakti.samon.ProdukListFragment2$ProdukLoader.deliverResult(ProdukListFragment2.java:255)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.bimasakti.samon.ProdukListFragment2$ProdukLoader.deliverResult(ProdukListFragment2.java:1)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:254)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-25 22:15:21.975: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This code xml for list_prod_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edsearchprod"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="45dp"
   android:inputType="textFilter|textAutoComplete"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:hint="Cari Produk"
   android:ems="10" >

   <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:listSelector="@color/color_bluecompat"
         android:gravity="center" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

please give me some answer. Thanks.

Comment: what is the ligne of code in ProdukListFragment2.java line 149 ? and just a suggestion , do you have the listView id in the xml file equals to `android:id="@android:id/list"` ??

Comment: line 149: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: your listView is null , so plz add the code of the xml layout file which contains your ListView , i think the problem is you are not retrieving the listView with the correct id

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that 'produk' is null when you pass it to the adapter constructor:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), produk, R.layout.list_prod, from, to);
```

The adapter then fails with a NullPointerException when calling its getCount() method which tries to return the size of 'produk'. The reason for 'produk' being null lies within your ProdukLoader class. You declare the return variable 'produk' but never instantiate it. Your declaration should be:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> produk = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Your loader will then always return a non-null List object, even if that list happens to be empty.

As an aside, your JSON request in loadInBackground() isn't returning any data (if it was, you would be getting a NullPointerException there instead when you do "produk.add(map);") but that is really a separate issue.